# Solving a system of simulataneous ordinary AND partial differential equations

Tags: differential-equations

I have an interesting system of equations I'm trying to solve, a PDE/ODE combo!!!! - involving a coupling of radiative and conductive heat exchange, for those interested. The general form of the problem is below:

Solving for solutions f(x,t) and g(t). There is also a given function k(f(1,t)) involved in one of the boundary conditions. The initial conditions f(x,0)=f0(x) & g(0) and constants a,b,c are all given.

*Governing equations*

d2f/dx2 = df/dt

dg/dt = a + k(f(1,t))*(f(1,t)-g(t)) - b*(g(t)^4 - c^4)

*Boundary conditions*

f(0,t)=1

df/dx(1)= -k(f(1,t))*(f(1,t)-g(t))

f(x,0)=f0(x)

g(0)=g0(x)

Any insight would be appreciated!!! I've been trying to come up with an analytical version of g(t) to reduce it to one PDE but because of f(1,t) in its governing equation it is difficult.

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In the [HeatTransfer Tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/HeatTransfer/HeatTransfer.html#1393540415) there is an example of this.